# Shortcuts to quickly accept or decline replacements in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am struggling with something that feels very basic (at least as a long-term Emacs user): When using the search & replace functionality in Visual Studio Code, I can accept/perform replacements one-by-one by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while the replacement is focused.

In order to *skip* one occurrence of the search string, I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move the focus back into the search field, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to the next occurrence, then (likely) press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to focus the replacement. There must be an easier way to do so, right?

Things I tried:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> inserts a newline
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> inserts a newline as well
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> replaces all occurrences at once
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> instantiates multiple cursors (and focuses the editor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this workflow.  **Focus must start in the Find input** (not the replace input box - if you enter the replace term second just <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus the replace field).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>  replaces an item

<kbd>Enter</kbd> skips to the next

[image: find skip replace demo]

Comment: Nice, thank you! The shortcut was absolutely not obvious to me (and it's not as trivial as I would have expected). How did you know? Should I have been able to discover it somewhere?